# Bayesian additive regression trees (BART) for classification analysis of gene expression data

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, classification, bart

I am interested in applying Bayesian additive regression trees (BART) for classification analysis of gene expression data. I am relatively new to R (and Bioconductor packages) and I am unable to find some code or vignette that I can use to learn from. I will be thankful if someone can point me in a good direction.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the [BayesTree](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesTree/index.html) package, from CRAN. I have no experience with it, so I cannot say if there are better option from there. Try looking at the [Machine Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) Task View, or directly through [www.rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/).

I don't know anything approaching in Bioconductor, but if the above package suits your needs I guess you won't have any problem with gene expression data. I know the [CMA](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioc-views/release/bioc/html/CMA.html) package offer a full-featured pipeline for supervised classification (see e.g., [CMA - A comprehensive Bioconductor package for super- vised classification with high dimensional data](http://www.ibe.med.uni-muenchen.de/organisation/mitarbeiter/020_professuren/boulesteix/pdf/cma.pdf), by Slawski et al.). Maybe you can plug BART method in addition to the available methods?

Comment: BayesTree is done by the inventors of BART, I believe. But the `bartMachine` package looks like a better option to me. (The only downside is it requires Java and interfaces to it via the `rJava` package, which might complicate things if your machine doesn't have Java installed.)

Comment: The `BART` and `dbarts`packages are reasonable alternatives nowadays.